# Invalidate cache of a "login protected" area upon logout

Tags: php, session, caching, http-caching

Say you're HTTP caching a login protected page (not critical banking info).

Now because you're using HTTP caching, logging out (destroying the session) will not have an effect on that cached page.

Currently, the only way I can think of is to explicitly set a sensible `max-age` cache value so it at least expires at some point.

E.g., members_area.php

```
\header('Cache-Control: max-age=60');
```

Other than this, are there better ways to invalidate `memebrs_area.php` in the user's browser when they click the logout button?

Comment: How about sending `Clear-Site-Data` upon logout?

Comment: @AlexKarshin that looks like it would work but I couldn't get it working. I can see Firefox response header containing the directive I set `Clear-Site-Data: "cache"` but the when I check back on the cached pages, they're still there.